# How to convert Russian date format to US date format?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

i want to change Russian Date to US format

```
String rDate = "28 августа 2017";
```

output :

```
String usDate = "28-08-2017";
```

Comment: You need to show your attempt at solving the problem so we can help you.

Comment: Try following.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546926/how-to-convert-russian-date-format-to-us-date-format#comment105262910_59546926

Comment: @atomskaze Actually, that is not always the case. The founders of Stack Overflow intended this site to be knowledge base, not a workshop. Some types of questions need an attempt at code, some do not. This one does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with [`withLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale(java.util.Locale)).

Parsing text.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("dd MMMM uuuu")
    .withLocale( new Locale("ru") )
;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(rDate, dateTimeFormatter);
```

Generating text.

```
String usDate = ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"));
=> 28-08-2017
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/O4jk6Q).